# RMAN Restore backupset from tape to disk

Tags: oracle, restore, rman

I am trying to restore a backupset tag from tape to disk, because I need to recover on another location (development environment).

The datacenter backups are made using Netbackup and I dont have access to it.

So, I am trying to restore through RMAN.

This is what I did so far:

```
rman target / catalog "user_rcat/passs@rcat" << EOF
run {
ALLOCATE CHANNEL CH00 TYPE 'SBT_TAPE';
SEND 'NB_ORA_CLIENT=oracle-db,NB_ORA_SID=ORCL,NB_ORA_SERV=bkp-server';
BACKUP BACKUPSET FROM TAG 'LVL0_05012015' FORMAT '/rman_backup/LVL0_05012015_%U' TAG 'JAN-05';
RELEASE CHANNEL CH00;
}
EOF
```

But, it says that it doesnt match any backups.

When I list

```
list backup tag 'LVL0_05012015'
```

The backups are there...

Anyone?

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message?

Comment: There is no error.. It only shows that there are no backup that match the specifications...

Answer (score 1):

In case someone like me find this thread even though it is one year old, I found an answer to this question directly in the Oracle Documentation (Database Backup and Recovery Reference 11.2) of the [RMAN BACKUP command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10643/rcmsynta007.htm#RCMRF107).

There, it is stated in the BACKUPSET sub-section that :

> You cannot back up from tape to tape or from tape to disk: only from disk to disk or disk to tape.

Also, the Oracle Support note [ID 2123833.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2123833.1) give some additional explanation and a possible alternative which consist in launching a RESTORE after having SET NEWNAME for datafiles aimed by the restore operation.